# QT Creator, Command Line Android App

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I have a pure NDK android app (just a jni folder). That cleanly compiles into a binary.
This binary can be pushed to the device and run, no problem.

I want to use QT not only as an editor but as a debug platform.
But the issue is that QT only understands Android apps as "APK"s. I want to set the environment to deploy/run/debug a command line app in the device.

Is this even possible? Looks quite simple in the theory, but not o simple to deal with QT flags and setup. I managed to create an Android APK from my app, but then it is unable to run the app, since it is not really a GUI app.

Any guide will be helpful, even to use another different approach with another IDE.

EDIT: I am on Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm wondering how you get the executable to run, when I push it after compiling it (not letting it package an APK), and run it (after having pushed all the Qt .sos over) I get a segmentation fault trying to execute it. I trimmed the `main()` down to a single `QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);` and it crashes right on that line. any tips?

Answer (score 1):

What you say is that QT creator doesn't "see" the native code behind the .apk ? The Gnu debugger is the only tool I know that can debug such code.

If you're on windows you can use the Nvidia TADP (tegra android dev kit) which ships a plugin for visual studio (works with community edition of visual studio). However it's a bit clunky and crashes when loading libraries at run time.

Comment: I mean, QT by default, is designed to attach and debug APKs. So it doesnt even start the app since it doesn have an intent to open with "am ...". Because this is a command line only executable. I am on ubuntu so unfortunately I can not tests VIsual Studio Plugins.